# Как найти наименьшее значение ключа в списке

Tags: python

есть такой response:

```
{"success":true,"currency":"RUB","data":[{"id":597772317,"market_hash_name":"MAC-10 | Nuclear Garden (Battle-Scarred)","price":11799,"class":575611913,"instance":302028390,"extra":{"float":"0.66711580753326","phase":"am_nuclear_skulls3_mac10"}},{"id":597646391,"market_hash_name":"MAC-10 | Nuclear Garden (Battle-Scarred)","price":11800,"class":575611913,"instance":302028390,"extra":{"float":"0.66149842739105","phase":"am_nuclear_skulls3_mac10"}}]}
```

в нем мне необходимо узнать id элемента в котором наименьшее значение price

Comment: `sorted(словарь['data'], key=lambda x: x['price'])[0]['id']`

Comment: @andreymal Элегантное решение. Не хотите оформить как ответ?

Comment: @nomnoms12 не хочу, к тому же оно вероятно не лучшее по производительности

Comment: @andreymal это поправимо :) `min(словарь['data'], key = lambda x: x['price'])['id']`

Answer (score 1):

***Пример:***

```py
import json


def main():
    response = '{"success":true,"currency":"RUB","data":[{"id":597772317,"market_hash_name":"MAC-10 | Nuclear Garden (Battle-Scarred)","price":11799,"class":575611913,"instance":302028390,"extra":{"float":"0.66711580753326","phase":"am_nuclear_skulls3_mac10"}},{"id":597646391,"market_hash_name":"MAC-10 | Nuclear Garden (Battle-Scarred)","price":11800,"class":575611913,"instance":302028390,"extra":{"float":"0.66149842739105","phase":"am_nuclear_skulls3_mac10"}}]}'
    d = json.loads(response)

    result = min(d['data'], key=lambda x: x['price'])['id']
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
597772317
```

---

Ответ был написан на основе комментариев ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026959/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5#comment1747233_1026959), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026959/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5#comment1747246_1026959)) участников [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) и [@extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324712/extrn).